# How do I make a dictionary out of a collection of FASTA?

Tags: python, dictionary, fasta

I have a text file with `FASTA` sequences that looks like this.

I need to create a dictionary which reads:

```
{header1\id number1: "ATCGTCAGGTCAGTCGTA", header2\idnumber2: "ATTGCAGTCATGCAG"}
```

> header1\idnumber

ATCGTCAG

GTCA

GTCGTA

> header2\idnumber2

ATTGCA

GTCA

TGCAG

etc.

So far I have managed to put my header as keys in this manner:

```
file1 = open("test.txt")
sequence = []
text = []
for line in file1:
    text.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
dic = {}
for thing in text:
    if thing[0]=='>':
        dic[thing] = ""

print dic
```

but I am at a loss on how to proceed further to join the sequences and put them as values under appropriate keys

EDIT: Actual part of the text file:

> FASTA658_B
>   CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCAGGCGCTCCGCCGAAGGTCT
>   ATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC
>
> TEK1-3586_CD
>   CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGAC
>   TGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT

Comment: what does the header and id look like?

Comment: it depends on the sequence,  there are a collection of letters, numbers and _

Comment: can you post a section of the text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict()` to make adding to the values easier

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(str)

with open('file') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        if line[0] == '>': #I'm assuming header/idnumber starts with '>'
            key = line.strip('\n')
        else:
            d[key] += line.strip('\n')
```

every line between keys will be a value to add to the dictionary. Strip the newlines and add it to value in the dict. It doesn't matter if the line is just a newline since it will add nothing to the string once the newline is stripped

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer, it solved my problem. Could you explain what is the difference between dic= {} and defaultdic ?

Comment: @Gab-1997 the values in dict are undefined when you create it but a defaultdict takes a type as its argument and every new key you add to the dict will automatically have a that type as it's value. You don't need the defaultdict in this case since you could just add `d[key] = ""` after you get the key. It's handy in cases when you would normally have to check whether the key was in there first since you don't need to check. You can add a new key and value or add to an existing value with the same line

Comment: @Gab-1997 You can read more about defaultdict() [here](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

using ordered dictionary

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re
import string

bad_chars = '\n>'
rgx = re.compile('[%s]' % bad_chars)
data = OrderedDict()
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            data[line.translate(string.maketrans("", "", ), bad_chars)] = ''
        else:
            data[data.keys()[-1]] += line.strip('\n')

print data
```